# Get 60 mins before and after a given timestamp - Shell/ksh

Tags: bash, shell, date

I am looking to get a time range from a given time. The start time should be 60 
mins before the given time and end time should be 60 mins after the given time.

Purpose:
The given time will be like an 'impact time', I am looking to get a suitable range of time around the impact time to be able to grab logs.

Example :
Given time is 2018-05-16 20:30:00
This is of the format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Please help me get: 
Start time is 2018-05-16 19:30:00
End time is 2018-05-16 21:30:00

This is going to run on a server that will be in PDT/PST always and the date-time is of the format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Timezones have an effect on time, I’m afraid...

Comment: @JeffSchaller  Sorry for the confusion , This script is going to run on a server that will be in PDT/PST always

Comment: Transitions between PDT and PST affect the time, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the timezone is set correctly, and GNU date, you can get the Unix timestamp, subtract, add 60 minutes and convert it back to the format needed:

```
$ ts=$(date -d "2018-05-16 21:30:00" +%s)  # For BSD date: date -jf "%F %T" "2018-05-16 21:30:00" +%s 
$ echo "$(date -d@$((ts - 3600)) +"%F %T")"
2018-05-16 20:30:00
$ echo "$(date -d@$((ts + 3600)) +"%F %T")"
2018-05-16 22:30:00
```

... I think this doesn't correctly account for leap seconds and [various other problems every programmer should know about time](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4128208).

Comment: This does not seem to work, I'm getting some weird year like 1972 ! does this command depend on the linux version ? Mine is Linux meade 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 28 14:23:39 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  and the output i got was : + date -d@-3600 '+%F %T'
+ sBegindate='1969-12-31 15:00:00'
+ date -d@3600 '+%F %T'
+ sEnddate='1969-12-31 17:00:00'
+ print ' Start date 1969-12-31 15:00:00 and End date 1969-12-31 17:00:00'
 Start date 1969-12-31 15:00:00 and End date 1969-12-31 17:00:00

Comment: Uh, why are you doing `date -d@-3600` and `date -d@3600`? 3600 seconds before and after the Unix epoch would of course be around 1970.